How is this AWS `PutObjectCommand` uploading the file I have sent?
I am trying out a new tool called SST which handles configuring AWS services and full stack web apps via code. In the API tutorial we create the following function to upload a file:
import { Resource } from "sst";
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import {
  S3Client,
  GetObjectCommand,
  PutObjectCommand,
  ListObjectsV2Command,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const s3 = new S3Client({});

export async function upload() {
  const command = new PutObjectCommand({
    Key: crypto.randomUUID(),
    Bucket: Resource.MyBucket.name,
  });
  const body = await getSignedUrl(s3, command);

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body
  };
}

That is the entire upload function. As you can see there is no explicit handling of any files - I had initially thought this would create an empty file in the specified S3 bucket.
Next, once our server is live we send a curl request with a file to upload:
curl --upload-file somefile.txt "$(curl https://sometestapi.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)"

However when I check the S3 bucket via the AWS console I can see somefile.txt and all its content is there. I'm really not understanding a) how this file is being picked up by the API - there is nothing explicit going on here, and b) how this file is then being sent to S3.
Logging command and body I see the following:
|  +26ms       {
|  +26ms         command: PutObjectCommand {
|  +26ms           middlewareStack: {
|  +26ms             add: [Function: add],
|  +26ms             addRelativeTo: [Function: addRelativeTo],
|  +26ms             clone: [Function: clone],
|  +26ms             use: [Function: use],
|  +26ms             remove: [Function: remove],
|  +26ms             removeByTag: [Function: removeByTag],
|  +26ms             concat: [Function: concat],
|  +26ms             applyToStack: [Function: cloneTo],
|  +26ms             identify: [Function: identify],
|  +26ms             identifyOnResolve: [Function: identifyOnResolve],
|  +26ms             resolve: [Function: resolve]
|  +26ms           },
|  +26ms           serialize: [AsyncFunction: se_PutObjectCommand],
|  +26ms           deserialize: [AsyncFunction: de_PutObjectCommand],
|  +26ms           input: {
|  +26ms             Key: '860d1393-4232-48fc-4d4b-b42c0c8a6473',
|  +26ms             Bucket: 'mytestprojectname-testbucket-tokfzzao'
|  +26ms           }
|  +26ms         }
|  +26ms       }
|  +26ms       {
|  +26ms         body: 'https://mytestprojectname-testbucket-tokfzzao.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/860d1393-4232-48fc-9d4a-b42c0c8a6473?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=<removed-credentials>&X-Amz-Date=20240607T170451Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=<removed-security-token>&X-Amz-Signature=<removed-signature>&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=PutObject'
|  +26ms       }

I have tried debugging all the available variables in the function to see if any contain the file being uploaded, but neither do. I had expected since no file is being explicitly handled it would not be uploaded to S3.
To add some additional context, when doing the same thing from a the client the process makes perfect sense. I first get the command, then I get the pre-signed URL for my S3 bucket, and then I upload the file to the URL. However in the above server-side examples the final step is entirely missing. Here is the client-side code:
const image = await fetch(url // pre-signed URL, {
                    body: file // file from HTML form,
                    method: "PUT",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": file.type,
                        "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename="${file.name}"`,
                    },
                });


That command just generates a signed URL that some other code can use to then upload the file. There must be some other code in your project (perhaps part of that library you linked) that is doing the actual upload.

Thanks @MarkB - came to the same conclusion. You're right. The actual upload is being done by the nested curl commands. The upload function doesn't do any uploading`

Note that SST is not new. It's at least 4 years old, based on commits to the GitHub repo.

Ok, I figured this out myself. The "problem" here is poorly named functions (and me being totally unfamiliar with curl). The upload function doesn't actually do any uploading, all it does is respond with a signed URL which I can then use to upload the file into S3.
curl --upload-file package.json "$(curl https://mytestapi.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)"

The key is the nested curl command. First that is called and in its place we get the signed S3 URL, then the outer curl command sends the specified file to our new S3 URL.
